# Magento 2 - Get country in billing address

Tags: magento2, billing-address, country-regions

I'm trying to get the country name from billing address. I have the address object and I see that the attribute `country_id` is always No but I'm sure the country is existed as it is displayed properly in the My account page. Below I printed all the attributes of the address object in the debug log.

```
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: === Billing Address Attribute Start === {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: entity_id = 9 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: entity_type_id =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: increment_id =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: parent_id = 9 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: attribute_set_id =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: created_at = 2016-08-27 05:46:38 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: updated_at = 2016-08-27 06:28:54 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: prefix =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: firstname = Alex {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: middlename =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: lastname =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: suffix =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: company = ABC Company {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: street = 11 Hoi Shing Road 
One Midtown {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: city = Tsuen Wan {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: country_id = No {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: region =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: region_id = 0 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: postcode = 852 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: telephone = 22233344 {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: fax =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: vat_id =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: vat_is_valid =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: vat_request_id =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: vat_request_date =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: vat_request_success =  {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-27 06:43:40] main.DEBUG: === Billing Address Attribute End === {"is_exception":false} []
```

Here is how I get the address object

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface //
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $this->logger->debug("CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver execute");

        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();
        $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();

    }

}
```

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_address_save_after">
        <observer name="customer_address_save_after_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: I see that you didn't set `region` and `region_id`? You can add more code lines about how you get the quote address object?

Comment: Edited the question to show how I get the address object.

Comment: Need to see your `events.xml` also.

Comment: added events.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here **$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();** is an object of **'Magento\Customer\Model\Address'** class and this class extend from **Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress**

So go to **Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress** has some get function that help you a lot. I add a line that help you to pick country.

```
$this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountry());
```

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface //
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $this->logger->debug("CustomerAddressSaveAfterObserver execute");

        $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();
        $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
        // get country code
        $this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountry());
        // get country name
        $this->logger->info($customerAddress->getCountryModel()->getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For billing address then this answer worked for me
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159497/70258 
Hope it help :)