# How to Get country name from country code in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, model, country-regions

i want to get country name from country code, i got the country code from the data order like this :

```
$data = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
$countryCode = $data['country_id'];
echo $countryCode;
```

it will print 'US' or any other country code, is there a way to get the country name from this country code?

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-regions-of-country-by-country-code-in-magento-2/ This is the simplest way to get code.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Create Block file,

```
   public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }
    
    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        return $country->getName();
    }
```

Call from phtml file,

```
<?= $block->getCountryname($countryCode);?>
```

Comment: Correct except you are missing a semi colon after $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode) it should be $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);

Comment: Is it possible to get country code from country name?

Comment: @Vindhuja Check https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-regions-of-country-by-country-code-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 10):

We can use `Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface` to get the country info:

```
/** @var \Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $country */

/** @var \Magento\Directory\Api\Data\CountryInformationInterface $data */
    $data = $country->getCountryInfo($data['country_id']);
    $data->getFullNameEnglish();
    $data->getFullNameLocale();
```

See more here about the returned values: `Magento\Directory\Api\Data\CountryInformationInterface`

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me, how to use this for getting engilsh country name in magento 2

Comment: This is just perfect.
i write a article based on this solution for details
https://blog.equaltrue.com/getting-country-from-country-code-in-magento-2/
this can be help you @AskBytes

Answer (score 1):

In the below example, in one of the task I need to print pdf on a custom way,
that’s why I need the billing address country and the shipping address country but, from sales order data I get it on as country id like “SE” (for Sweden)

in the method, you can value in two way on method getCountryName(), in English or in local.

CountryInformationAcquirerInterface is used here.

here is the full code

```
namespace Equaltrue\Orderprint\Block\Order;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Directory\Api\CountryInformationAcquirerInterface;

class Print extends Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $countryInformationAcquirerInterface;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirerInterface
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        CountryInformationAcquirerInterface $countryInformationAcquirerInterface,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->countryInformationAcquirerInterface = $countryInformationAcquirerInterface;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Current Data
     */
    public function getOrderData()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id', 0);
        $order =  $this->getOrder($orderId);

        /*
         * Get billing Address
         * */
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $firstNameBilling = $billingAddress->getFirstName();
        $lastNameBilling = $billingAddress->getLastName();
        $streetBilling = implode( ", ", $billingAddress->getStreet());
        $cityBilling = $billingAddress->getCity();
        $postCodeBilling = $billingAddress->getPostCode();
        $countryIdBilling = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
        $countryNameBilling = $this->getCountryName($countryIdBilling);
        $telephoneBilling = "T: ".$billingAddress->getTelephone();
        $formattedBillingAddress = $firstNameBilling." ".$lastNameBilling."<br>". $streetBilling."<br>". $cityBilling.",".$postCodeBilling."<br>".$countryNameBilling."<br>".$telephoneBilling;

        /*
         * Get billing Address
         * */
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $firstNameShipping = $shippingAddress->getFirstName();
        $lastNameShipping = $shippingAddress->getLastName();
        $streetShipping = implode( ", ", $shippingAddress->getStreet());
        $cityShipping = $shippingAddress->getCity();
        $postCodeShipping = $shippingAddress->getPostCode();
        $countryIdShipping = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
        $countryNameShipping = $this->getCountryName($countryIdShipping);
        $telephoneShipping = "T: ".$shippingAddress->getTelephone();
        $formattedShippingAddress = $firstNameShipping." ".$lastNameShipping."<br>". $streetShipping."<br>". $cityShipping.",".$postCodeShipping."<br>".$countryNameShipping."<br>".$telephoneShipping;

        return array(
            "formatted_billing_address" => $formattedBillingAddress,
            "formatted_shipping_address" => $formattedShippingAddress
        );
    }

    /**
     * Getting Country Name
     * @param string $countryCode
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return null|string
     * */
    public function getCountryName($countryCode, $type="local"){
        $countryName = null;
        try {
            $data = $this->countryInformationAcquirerInterface->getCountryInfo($countryCode);
            if($type == "local"){
                $countryName = $data->getFullNameLocale();
            }else {
                $countryName = $data->getFullNameLocale();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {}
        return $countryName;
    }

    protected function getOrder($id)
    {
        return $this->orderRepository->get($id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the given model of **country** and its methods:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, 
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory    
    ) {  
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    }
```

One of the method it provides is `$this->countryFactory->create()->getName();` .You can use the model factory based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this for the order success page. The easiest method to call it in a phtml file is to use:

```
    $countrycode = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData("country_id");
    $country = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country')- 
    >load("$countrycode")->getName();
    echo $country;
```

The customer_address_entity table doesn't hold the country but does hold the country code. This gets the country code from the order and loads the country name associated with it.

Answer (score -2):

Get country name by country code using objectManager.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $countryCode = 'US'; // Enter country code here
    $country = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country')->load($countryCode)->getName();
    echo $country;
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $allowerdContries = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries')->getAllowedCountries() ;
            $countryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($allowerdContries);

            $countries = array();
            foreach($allowerdContries as $countryCode)
            {
                    if($countryCode)
                    {

                        $data = $countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
                        $countries[$countryCode] =  $data->getName();
                    }
            }
```