# Magento 2.3.0 Get Country Name

Tags: magento2, php, module, phtml, magento2.3

I'm trying to insert the current store country name through a CMS Page/Block by following this [article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159494/how-to-get-country-name-from-country-code-in-magento-2).

I've created a Block file **countryname.php** in

> app/code/Vendor/Countryname/Block

with the following

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Countryname\Block;
class Countryname extends \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory

{  
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        echo $country->getName();
    }
    ?>
```

Then created a countryname.phtml in

> app/code/Vendor/Countryname/view/frontend/templates

with the following

```
<?php
echo $block->getCountryname($countryCode);
?>
```

and have used this to call the block from CMS Page/Static Block

> {{block class="Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname"
>   template="Vendor_Countryname::countryname.phtml" }}

However I get this error on the frontend

> Error filtering template: Invalid block type:
>   Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname

and this is error in the exception log

> main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type:
>   Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid
>   block type: Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname at
>   /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:275,
>   ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
>   Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname does not exist at
>   /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"}
>   []

---

UPDATE

Thanks to **[magefms](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/74200/magefms)** this is a partial solution he provided.

In the countryname.php

```
<?php 

namespace Koshmart\Countryname\Block; 

class Countryname extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{ 
protected $_countryFactory; 


public function __construct( 
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
\Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory, 
array $data = [] 
){ 
parent::__construct($context, $data); 
$this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory; 

} 

public function getCountryname($countryCode){ 

$country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode); 
echo $country->getName(); 
} 
}
?>
```

in the countryname.phtml

```
<?php 
echo $block->getCountryname('us');
?>
```

and use this in CMS page/static block to get the country name

> {{block name="koshmart_countryname"
>   class="Koshmart\Countryname\Block\Countryname"
>   template="countryname.phtml"}}

However the country ID "us" etc has to be manually entered in the phtml file. It does not dynamically get the country ID and then get the country name on the CMS Page/static block.

Comment: Have you found solution ?

Comment: Yes thanks to magefms, but not a full solution, its does not work dynamically. The country ID needs to be manually inserted in the phtml file for it to show the country name in CMS page/static block.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your block file

***blockfilename.php***

```
use Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory;

class blockName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_locationFactory;

public function __construct(
        ...................................................... 
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        ..................................................
    ) {
        .........................................
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        .........................................
    }

   public function getCountryname($countryCode)
  {    
    $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
    return $country->getName();
}
```

}

In You .phtml file call this like

***filename.phtml***

```
<?php

 $countryName = $block->getCountryname($country_code);  // pass your country code herer

echo $countryname;

?>
```

add this both file into one layout file

***layputfilename.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Storelocator</title>
    </head> 

      <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">

                  <block class="[vendore_name]\[module_name]\Block\blockfilename" name="block_file_name" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::filename.phtml" />

            </referenceContainer>

      </body>
</page>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **file name** to be the same with the **class name**

Like this one :

```
class Countryname extends....
```

File name should be

**`Countryname.php`**

Comment: I changed the file name as suggested, now the page itself doesn't load. If I remove the call block shortcode from the CMS page then the page loads, appears like its a issue with the code?

Comment: try to declare this  `_countryFactory` on top of the public function line , declare it like `protected $_countryFactory;`

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you post the full code, as I'm not sure where I should be declaring it.

Comment: `<?php
namespace Vendor\Countryname\Block;
class Countryname extends \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory

{  
 protected $_countryFactory;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        echo $country->getName();
    }
    ?>`

Comment: Still doesn't work, page does'nt load, however in the editor I use it shows this error on the code " syntax error, unexpected '; ' ,expecting, 'T_FUNCTION or T_CONST"

Comment: Try this one `<?php
namespace Vendor\Countryname\Block;
class Countryname extends \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
{  
 protected $_countryFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        echo $country->getName();
    }
}`

Comment: the problem is with the closing tag of your class , use the new code I commented. and try again. Hopefully it will work now

Comment: page loads now, but gives this error "Error filtering template: Vendor\Countryname\Block\Countryname does not implement BlockInterface"

Comment: One last try this one `<?php
namespace Vendor\Countryname\Block;
class Countryname extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{  
 protected $_countryFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode);
        echo $country->getName();
    }
}`

Comment: that one should fix the problem now.

Comment: I tried it, with and without the end php tag ?>, with ?> its a blank page, without ?> its a page load error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88079/discussion-between-magefms-and-user2240778).

Comment: Are you on chat?