# sql query for shipping countries from my sales order

Tags: magento2, shipping, sql, countries

I need to write a SQL query to get all `countries` where we have shipped al orders.

Which table has all `sales order` countries?
I am not able to find all the countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this query you can get countries of shipped orders

```
SELECT o.increment_id, oa.country_id FROM sales_order o
INNER JOIN sales_order_address oa ON o.entity_id=oa.parent_id
INNER JOIN sales_shipment s ON o.entity_id=s.order_id
WHERE oa.address_type='shipping'
```

The join for `sales_order_address`  is to get shipping country

And the join for `sales_shipment` is to get the orders which are shipped.

Comment: Hi, i have written a similar query, but i am not able to country name from its country_id
i have searched for tables  but not able to find it

Comment: You wont find it in database, it is actually in locale of core magento. If you want to get country name by it's code, then you can do it programmatically, follow this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159497/31910